# Convert GLSL to C#

Tags: c#, glsl

Hello guys can someone help me with the conversion of glsl to c#? i'm new to glsl and i really need alot of help! gladly appreciate all your helps! :)

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D tex;

void main()
{
 vec4 pixcol = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
 vec4 colors[3];
 colors[0] = vec4(0.,0.,1.,1.);
 colors[1] = vec4(1.,1.,0.,1.);
 colors[2] = vec4(1.,0.,0.,1.);
 float lum = (pixcol.r+pixcol.g+pixcol.b)/3.;
 int ix = (lum < 0.5)? 0:1;
 vec4 thermal = mix(colors[ix],colors[ix+1],(lum-float(ix)*0.5)/0.5);
 gl_FragColor = thermal;
}
```

Comment: The right question is probably how to convert to HLSL? Are you using Direct3d? OpenGL and D3D shaders are just a tiny part of a pretty large API, not part of a language.

Comment: hello! @starmole thanks for your reply! i'm actually creating this thermal imaging effect c# windows form application and the only reference i got was from http://coding-experiments.blogspot.sg/2010/10/thermal-vision-pixel-shader.html and i totally do not understand the codes. i've added the opentk to my visual studios too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to convert GLSL to c# to use it, as it is used by OpenGL API directly. There are several OpenGl wrappers for c#, not sure if all support shaders, but openTk supports for sure, example is here:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("vertex_shader.glsl"))
{
    GL.ShaderSource(m_shader_handle, sr.ReadToEnd());
}
```

You can load shader either from file, either from string directly:

```
string shader = "void main() { // your shader code }"
GL.ShaderSource(m_shader_handle, shader);
```

Comment: This sure helps alot! Thank you so so so so much for your help :) @Giedrius

Comment: @user2598264 mark it as an answer then to show your appreciation.

Comment: sorry don't mind me asking but do you know of any APIs or SDKs for calculating temperature for fever through a thermal image? @Giedrius

Answer (score 0):

The c# code that would be analogous to your reference code is (pseudo-code)

```
//Declares the texture/picture i.e.  uniform sampler2D tex;
Bitmap x = new Bitmap();

float[] main()
{
    // Looks up the color of a pixel for the specified coordinates, the color (as a rule of thumb) 
    // a normalized value i.e. vec4 pixcol = texture2D(tex, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
    Color pixcolUnnormalized=  x.GetPixel();
    float[] pixcol = new float[] { pixcolUnnormalized.r / 255.0f, pixcolUnnormalized.g / 255.0f, pixcolUnnormalized.b / 255.0f, pixcolUnnormalized.a / 255.0f);

    //Setup coefficients  i.e.  vec4 colors[3];  colors[0] = vec4(0.,0.,1.,1.);  colors[1] = vec4(1.,1.,0.,1.);  colors[2] = vec4(1.,0.,0.,1.);     
    float[] color1[] = new float[] { 0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0 };
    float[] color2[] = new float[] { 0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0 };
    float[] color3[] = new float[] { 0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0 };
    float[ float[] ] colors = new float[] { colors1, colors2, colors3 };

    ///Obtain luminance value from the pixel. 
    float lum = (pixcol[0]+pixcol[1] +pixcol[2])/3.;
    int ix = (lum < 0.5)? 0:1;

    //Interpolate the color values i.e.         vec4 thermal = mix(colors[ix],colors[ix+1],(lum-float(ix)*0.5)/0.5);
    float[] thermal = new float[] {
          colors[ix][0] * ( 1 -  (lum-float(ix)*0.5)/0.5)  )  + colors[ix + 1][0] * (lum-float(ix)*0.5)/0.5)
          colors[ix][1] * ( 1 -  (lum-float(ix)*0.5)/0.5)  )  + colors[ix + 1][1] * (lum-float(ix)*0.5)/0.5)
          colors[ix][2] * ( 1 -  (lum-float(ix)*0.5)/0.5)  )  + colors[ix + 1][2] * (lum-float(ix)*0.5)/0.5)
          colors[ix][3] * ( 1 -  (lum-float(ix)*0.5)/0.5)  )  + colors[ix + 1][3] * (lum-float(ix)*0.5)/0.5)
    };

    //return the value
    return thermal;
}
```

Comment: Thank so much this is helpful! :D don't mind me asking but do you know of any APIs or SDKs for calculating temperature for fever through a thermal image? @Lawrence Kok